# DOS Protection in Azure Web APP

Tags: azure-web-app-service, ddos

We are using Azure Web APP for for our FrontEnd site. Recently we have discovered DOS attack on our website. When I googled around I got to know solution for Azure Cloud Services. Is there any way, Azure Web APP can be protected with out of box support..

Answer (score 5):

Azure Web Sites enabled the Dynamic IP Restrictions module for IIS8.You can protect your Azure Web App from DDOS Attacks by configuring Dynamic Ip Security under `System.WebServer` in your App's web.config file as follows.

```
   <security>
  <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="NotFound">
  <!--<denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="20" />-->
    <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="20" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="5000"/>     
  </dynamicIpSecurity>
</security>
```

Read Reference For More Information
https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/